# flask-restul nested resources

Tags: python, rest, flask-restful

Im refactoring my rest api server to use Flask-RESTful, and im having some doubt about some particular cases where i need to get a list of resources that belong to another. Some thing like this:

```
/api/v1/users/john/orders
```

How would you design this? Because if I have a resource called Orders, I need to know from which user i have to get the orders from. But how can i let the resource know about the user? i dont see any __ init __ method where i can specify parameters to the resources.

I thought about doing something like this when registering the Orders resource:

```
api.add_resources(Orders, '/api/v1/users/<string:username>/orders')
```

But the how can i access the **string:username** in the Orders resource??

I guess one solution would be to do:

```
api.add_resources(Orders, '/api/v1/orders/')
```

and send query parameters specifying the user i want to get the orders from, but I wanted to know if its possible to do something like the above example.

Comment: Have you figured out how to do that?

Comment: Sorry forgot about this one. Yes! ill edit the question so you can see it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, i finally got it. Here's the solution

Lets suppose we have a endpoint of users that can be looked by name, and the users have orders that can also be queried. orders query will be a generic thing, it would only need the corresponding query parameters, and will need to know on which user it will have to look for orders:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Api


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['DEBUG'] = True

from views import *

api = Api(app)
api.add_resource(OrdersQuery, '/api/v1/user/<string:name>/orders/query/')
```

And when defining the resources class:

```
class OrdersQuery(Resource):
    def get(self, name):
        ## do something with name, like retrieving the user
        ## probably grab the orders and apply the query with the params from the url
        return jsonify({
            'result_list': [..something in here..]
        })
```

As you can see, you are using the variable part of the url, the name of the user, for the query orders endpoint.

Comment: How could I do something like /api/v1/user/<string:name>/orders/<string:id>/query/ with flask_restful? would appreciate if you could point me in the right direction...

Comment: you would do the same, only that you will have 2 parameters in the url string and the get method. But if you are already sending the order id, then why would you send a query? anyway, if that's what you need you can do it the same way as above adding the new parameter.